# Loading every class in a package

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

I'm currently using reflection to get all loaded classes from the `classes` field in `ClassLoader` and then checking if `getPackage` is equal to the package I'm searching for. One problem I'm having with this is that the classes aren't getting loaded by the `ClassLoader` but I have no way to load them myself using `Class.forName` because I won't know the name of the classes since they are dynamically loaded and always changing. One thing the classes all have in common is that they extend `Module`. How would I go about loading all the classes from a package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection seems to answer this

Comment: @iluxa I can get all the classes in the package, but only if they are loaded

Comment: explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection/520344#520344)

Comment: Yup, and it's indeed a problem. It seems you need to figure out your classpath, go through it, inspect the Jar files etc. Nothing you can do cheaply.

Comment: There is a Reflections API https://code.google.com/p/reflections/ which does this pretty well. I have personally used it to reflect over packages to find subtypes of a class when no meaningful use has happened on that class, and the class loader has not loaded them yet. I believe it functions like iluxa has suggested, by evaluating the working directory / jar contents.

Comment: If you are using a newer jdk now, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28833044/2711488) will hint you to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [reflections API](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) it works for sure. If it doesn't you might set it up the wrong way. I just made up this example and it prints all of the classes in the package independently from any classloader.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.FieldAnnotationsScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.MemberUsageScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.MethodAnnotationsScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.MethodParameterNamesScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.MethodParameterScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.TypeAnnotationsScanner;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.reflections.util.FilterBuilder;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections();
        FilterBuilder TestModelFilter = new FilterBuilder().include("com.test.*");

        reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setUrls(Arrays.asList(ClasspathHelper.forClass(Runner.class))).filterInputsBy(TestModelFilter)
                .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new TypeAnnotationsScanner(), new FieldAnnotationsScanner(),
                        new MethodAnnotationsScanner(), new MethodParameterScanner(), new MethodParameterNamesScanner(),
                        new MemberUsageScanner()));

        Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
        System.out.println(allClasses);
        for (Iterator it = allClasses.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Class<? extends Object> clazz = (Class<? extends Object>) it.next();
            System.out.println(clazz.getCanonicalName());
        }
    }

}
```

I added all the imports by intention, so you can see what API it uses. Does this work for you?