# Why doesn't reflection work when a class returns Lambdas

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, annotations, java-8

I have encountered a somewhat strange behaviour. I use annotations to mark certain classes with a particular purpose, and then I use org.reflections library to find all the classes with the particular annotation. However when a class implements a method that returns a lambda function, the reflection won't find the annotated class anymore. The signature of the class is unchanged.

Example of annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   String someValue();
}
```

Using the annotation (EDIT - added the BaseClass):

```
public class BaseClass {

    public Consumer<Integer> doSomething(){ return null;}
}


@MyAnnotation(someValue = "a")
public class FooBar extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    public Consumer<Integer> doSomething() {
        return null;
    }
}



@MyAnnotation(someValue = "bazbar")
public class BarClass extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    public  Consumer<Integer> doSomething(){
        return (x) -> {};
    }
}
```

Finding the annotations

```
private static final Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mypackage");

Set<Class<?>> clazzes  = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```

Now - the set 'clazzes' only contains **1 single class**, the FooBar class. If I remove the lambda return value from the BazBar class that one too shows up, but as soon as one method in the class returns a lambda the reflection wont work.

I'm lost, any ideas?

Comment: does it work if you `return new Conumser<Integer> () { ... };`?

Comment: Yes, if if return new Consumer<Integer> () {...} it works, then both classes show up in the reflection, but when the lambda expression is uses it doesn't show up.

Comment: I have used your code in a simple setup and `clazzes` contains both classes `FooBar` and `BarClass`. I used `reflections` version 0.9.9. How does your `BaseClass.java` look like?

Comment: I've updated the example above with the BaseClass - I've used 0.9.9-RC1, could not make it work though...

Comment: @Idlewood Tried your example with `0.9.9-RC1` and can confirm that it's not working. So update the version from `0.9.9-RC1` to `0.9.9` and it works.

Comment: @SubOptimal yeah! tried that too just now, works! Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

From the [issues list](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/issues/list) it seems that this library isn't fit for Java 8 features yet. I think your best bet is reporting this problem and maybe provide a fix.

Comment: Seems like version 0.9.9 has a solution for this issue

Answer (score 2):

You may perform the lookup without any third-party code as follows:

```
private static <T extends Annotation> Set<Class<?>> getAnnotated(
        Class<?> context, Class<T> anno) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    URI clURI = context.getResource(context.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI();
    if(!clURI.getScheme().equals("file")) try {
        FileSystems.getFileSystem(clURI);
    } catch(FileSystemNotFoundException ex) {
        FileSystems.newFileSystem(clURI, Collections.emptyMap());
    }
    String pkg=context.getPackage().getName();
    return Files.list(Paths.get(clURI).getParent())
        .map(p->p.getFileName().toString())
        .filter(s->s.endsWith(".class"))
        .map(s->s.substring(0, s.length()-6))
        .map(s-> { try {
            return context.getClassLoader().loadClass(pkg+'.'+s);
          } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) { return null; } })
        .filter(c -> c!=null && c.isAnnotationPresent(anno))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

The advantage of `Path` over good old `File` is that it abstracts over the filesystem (storage) and thus can be used to list package members even if the `Class` is stored in a jar file (or any other kind of class storage for which a `FileSystemProvider` exists).

You may use it as

```
Set<Class<?>> clazzes  = getAnnotated(context, MyAnnotation.class);
```

where `context` is a `Class` within the package for which you want to get a annotated classes.